# Storing a JsonObject using Volley

Tags: android, json, android-volley

[This](http://loklak.org/api/search.json?q=apple) is my API, and [here is the POJO to the JSON](https://gist.github.com/shaheenkdr/2377917b5203bb90a6f1).
I'm wondering how to store a JSON Object using Volley.

Here is my code so far:

```
JsonArrayRequest TweetReq = new JsonArrayRequest(URL1,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>()
{
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
        Log.d("WORKING RESPONSE:::::", response.toString());
        //hidePDialog();

        SharedPreferences Tempx = getSharedPreferences("ActivitySession", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor edx = Tempx.edit();
        edx.putString("GSON_FEED", response.toString());
        edx.apply();

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
        JsonArray jArray = parser.parse(Tempx.getString("GSON_FEED","")).getAsJsonArray();

        //ArrayList<MainPojo> uid = new ArrayList<MainPojo>();

        for(JsonElement obj : jArray )
        {
            MainPojo cse = gson.fromJson( obj , MainPojo.class);
            TweetList.add(cse);
        }
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        // Parsing json

    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
    {
        SharedPreferences Tempx = getSharedPreferences("ActivitySession", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        try{
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
            JsonArray jArray = parser.parse(Tempx.getString("GSON_FEED","")).getAsJsonArray();

            for(JsonElement obj : jArray )
            {
                MainPojo cse = gson.fromJson( obj , MainPojo.class);
                TweetList.add(cse);
            }
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            VolleyLog.d("EDUKNOW::::", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //hidePDialog();
    }
});
```

And this returns an `IllegalStateException` saying : `This is not a JSON Array`,
which makes sense, but how do I store it like an `Object`?

**EDIT1**
added logcat .

```
01-08 20:01:08.688 4764-4764/com.fossasia.loklak W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This is not a JSON Array.
01-08 20:01:08.688 4764-4764/com.fossasia.loklak W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.JsonElement.getAsJsonArray(JsonElement.java:106)
01-08 20:01:08.688 4764-4764/com.fossasia.loklak W/System.err:     at com.fossasia.loklak.Activities.MainActivity$2.onErrorResponse(MainActivity.java:105)
01-08 20:01:08.688 4764-4764/com.fossasia.loklak W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.Request.deliverError(Request.java:564)
01-08 20:01:08.688 4764-4764/com.fossasia.loklak W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:101)
01-08 20:01:08.688 4764-4764/com.fossasia.loklak W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
01-08 20:01:08.688 4764-4764/com.fossasia.loklak W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-08 20:01:08.689 4764-4764/com.fossasia.loklak W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
01-08 20:01:08.689 4764-4764/com.fossasia.loklak W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
01-08 20:01:08.689 4764-4764/com.fossasia.loklak W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-08 20:01:08.689 4764-4764/com.fossasia.loklak W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
01-08 20:01:08.689 4764-4764/com.fossasia.loklak W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: JsonObject. best thing to do is use parsing library like jackson or moshi

Comment: Because the response is a JSONObject, so you should use JsonObjectRequest instead of JsonArrayRequest.

Answer (score -1):

```
try{
   JsonArray jArray = parser.parse(Tempx.getString("GSON_FEED","")).getAsJsonArray();
   for(JsonElement obj : jArray )
    {
        MainPojo cse = gson.fromJson( obj , MainPojo.class);
        TweetList.add(cse);
    }
}catch(Throwable e) {

    JsonElement obj = parser.parse(Tempx.getString("GSON_FEED","")).getAsJsonObject();
    MainPojo cse = gson.fromJson( obj , MainPojo.class);
    TweetList.add(cse);   

}
```

Comment: but the `onErrorResponse()` is getting loaded by default , as I guess this is a JSON Object, so, literally, would this make any difference?

Comment: JsonArrayRequest TweetReq = new JsonArrayRequest  => JsonObjectRequest TweetReq = new JsonObjectRequest